# ImportError: openpyxl is required for loading excel format files

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl, psychopy

I am using anaconda spyder 2.7 on windows 10 64 bit. I am also using psychopy software. There is an error coming which says openpyxl is required to load excel format files. I have installed openpyxl, but still there is a same error. I have also tried to modify the data.py line 29:

```
from 
openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter 
into:
openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

but there is no difference. 
I am sending you the code and traceback. It would be really helpful if someone can solve this error.

```
base_dir =  os.path.normpath('C:\\Users\\ravikumar.mevada\\Gustometer\\qmix\\examples')
conditions_file = os.path.join(base_dir, 'fat_taste.xlsx')
data_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Data_out_fat')
outfile = os.path.join(data_dir,'output_fat_taste')

#import .xlsx file
conditions = data.importConditions(conditions_file)

#screen resolution #TODO: not used
width = GetSystemMetrics(0) 
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)

#assign to each taste a specific pump
tastants_pumps = {'sweet1':pump_1,'sweet2':pump_3,'sweet3':pump_4, 'water':pump_5}
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-9-291e52893b5d>", line 7, in <module>
conditions = data.importConditions(conditions_file)

 File "C:\Users\ravikumar.mevada\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\data.py", line 2667, in importConditions
 raise ImportError('openpyxl is required for loading excel '

 ImportError: openpyxl is required for loading excel format files, but it was not found.
```

Comment: Forget the PsychoPy complications for the time time being, this just sounds like a problem with the installation of openpyxl. i.e. what happens with a python script that contains nothing but the line `import openpyxl`?

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I have tryed and everything is fine now with openpyxl. I just uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill When I am running separate code for openpyxl, there is no problem, but when I am running my main program with psychopy I am getting the same error. Do you have any suggestions to deal with this problem?